# How can I do a sequencer view?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am writing and app which should allow the user to position sounds on a scrollable timeline (track):

```
_________xxxx__________x________
```

When you hit "play" in the app, a cursor will move from left to right and will trigger sounds at the respecting time.

it should be possible to have more tracks in parallel:

```
_________xxxx__________x________
_________xx____xx______x________
___xx__________xxxx_____________
```

Since the tracks can be long, the view should be scrollable. Now I wondered if there is a component/library out there which I could use to save some time of writing a custom view from scratch.

I thought about using a horizontal staggered recyclerview, but I am not sure if this would work.

I am solely concerned about the UI part here.
Great things to have would be:

- Scrollable
- Drag and drop support
- Zoomable
- Support for a moving cursor (to see the current play position)

Do you know of any components which would allow me to build on top..?

Comment: ... what about a GridView?

Comment: It's very logical to me to think to a Drum Machine or a Tracker, which, in turn, are multitrack sequencers. And I always imagine them as grids. Where the rows are the instruments and the columns the beats (Drum Machines / Sequencers). Or the other way round (trackers).

Comment: @ModularSynth yes, I think this might work. Only problem might be to support drag without snap (to grid). In my case it should be possible to position the sample wherever you like, not just on a grid cell.
Also I don't know if its easy to implement drag and drop inside of a GridView

Comment: Also the length of the sample might not fit into a single grid cell -> even more complicated

Comment: **1** - This could be complicate. And not very conformal. A sound *should* start at a beat. **2** - It's only a matter of drawing the part which fits. Or simplify everything and just highlight/dehiglight the cell. After all, it's on the same "line" of the instrument, so you don't have to draw n waveforms. Just like `HiHat: 000x000x00xx00x0`. You would drag and drop the sample only on the first column or row. And, even better, you could light on the corresponding "led" when that sample is played at that beat.

Comment: Something like [this](http://www.doepfer.de/a157.htm) might be inspiring.

Comment: :D who says that a sound SHOULD start on a beat? In fact I just used the sound analogy to simplify my usecase. What I am actually trying to do is a LED light control automation app...

Comment: A sound should ALWAYS start on a beat. Or you'llend up with a **cacophony**... ;)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NQPcup4sbAE
Besides that what about non rhythmical music? Not always there is a need to place sounds on beats.

Comment: syncopation = cacophony. And, well, most "classical" sequencers are beat based. At least the ones you make using a 555 + 4017 (8-10 steps - expandable) or a counter + a 4067 (16 steps) or...